# Mongo Scala Play - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getApplicationName()Ljava/lang/String;]

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm trying to do a basic CRUD on a scala play mongo prototype. The code works as a standalone main method - but when executed as a play application invoked through a controller, getting runtime exceptions

```
[debug] Running task... Cancel: Null, check cycles: false, forcegc: true
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[error] application - 

! @7b9n058gm - Internal server error, for (GET) [/mongoTestUserCollection] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getApplicationName()Ljava/lang/String;]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getApplicationName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:463)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getApplicationName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.applyConnectionString(MongoClientSettings.java:181)
        at org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient$.apply(MongoClient.scala:62)
        at org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient$.apply(MongoClient.scala:50)
        at com.test.db.mongodb.MongoDBConnector$.<init>(MongoDBConnector.scala:25)
        at com.test.db.mongodb.MongoDBConnector$.<clinit>(MongoDBConnector.scala)
        at com.test.db.mongodb.Repo$class.$init$(Repo.scala:15)
        at com.test.db.mongodb.UserSessionHistory2MongoDBCollection$.<init>(Repo.scala:42)
        at com.test.db.mongodb.UserSessionHistory2MongoDBCollection$.<clinit>(Repo.scala)
        at com.test.controllers.AsyncController$$anonfun$testUserSessionHistory2MongoDBCollection$1.apply(AsyncController.scala:83)
        at com.test.controllers.AsyncController$$anonfun$testUserSessionHistory2MongoDBCollection$1.apply(AsyncController.scala:83)
```

I tried changing the driver version - yet same errors

Build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.3.0",
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-bson" % "2.3.0",
```

Connector:

```
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://server-internal.com:27017/")
  val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[HistoryRecord]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
  val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db-test").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
```

This code works if I invoke it as below:

```
object MongoService {
  def makeMongoCalls(repo: Repo) = {
    repo.insertHistoryRecords(5)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    makeMongoCalls(UserSessionHistory2MongoDBCollection)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getApplicationName()Ljava/lang/String;

Is very often happens in the case of libraries conflict.

1. Run `sbt clean`
2. Check if you do not have other MongoDB driver in dependencies. Some library that can use it.
3. Try to remove `"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-bson" % "2.3.0"` from dependencies. The `"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.3.0"` already have it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I removed the scala-bson and still got the error. Then I figured that I started the code with Casbah and Salat - which I removed and after that it worked. Appreciate the help.