# MongoDB Scala client- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getUuidRepresentation()Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to use the Mongo scala client, but when I init the client I get the following exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getUuidRepresentation()Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;`

In my project, I also use Mongo java client for other purposes.

I saw this [question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287521/mongo-scala-play-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-mongodb-connectionstring-get) so I guess it is probably the same issue (libraries conflicts).

The problem is that I prefer to keep the design of 2 clients- one java and one scala (BTW, each client is for a different Mongo cluster).

I wonder how can I achieve that.

build.sbt:

```
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.11.1",
"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.9.0",
```

code:

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient(server)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your referenced question link is broken.

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/ says scala driver is merged into java driver, so you should be using the same driver versions for both?

Comment: Can't find org.mongodb.scala in the package org.mongodb, this is why I imported it.

Comment: what is `server` in your code sample?

Comment: A string, mongodb://<server_name>:<port>
I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no solution for having 2 clients. Eventually, I used one java client :(